# How to get second latest row from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new in php. I want to print second latest row from my db.

Using the following code i print out first latest row from db

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
$q_opinion="SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
    inner join
(
  select max(notification_date) notification_date,
    client_id
  from og_ratings
  group by client_id
  ORDER BY notification_date DESC
) r2
  on r.notification_date = r2.notification_date
  and r.client_id = r2.client_id
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)";
$result = mysql_query($q_opinion) or die;
$rating = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $rating[] = $row['client_id'];
  $action[] = $row['atitle'];
  $opinion[] = $row['opinion'];
  $date[] = $row['notification_date'];
  $lrating[] = $row['ltitle'];
  $srating[] = $row['stitle'];
}
for ($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++) {
    if ($rating[$i] == "")continue;
     ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
          <td><?= $rating[$i] ?> </td>
           <td><?= $date[$i] ?> </td>
          <td><?= $opinion[$i] ?> </td>
         <td><?= $action[$i] ?> </td>
          <td><?= $lrating[$i] ?> </td>
           <td><?= $srating[$i] ?> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php   
}
?>
```

Following Lines from my code

```
WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)";
```

having multiple results

My code result is

[image]

and this is first latest record of my db

Now i want to fetch directly second latest record. I dont have any idea how i can do it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you can use order by id desc and limit 2,1

Comment: Where i can use order by in my query?

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end of your SQL query `order by client_id desc limit 1,1`

Comment: its print only one record. I mentioned in my question my subquery contain multiple record

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$q_opinion="SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
inner join
(
  select max(notification_date) notification_date,
  client_id
  from og_ratings
  group by client_id
  ORDER BY notification_date DESC
) r2
  on r.notification_date = r2.notification_date
  and r.client_id = r2.client_id
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50) ORDER BY c.id DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Comment: Its only print single record but as i mention in my question my subquery contain multiple records and i want to print it all

Comment: second row of all records

Comment: you need even records?

Comment: No i need only two rows from my db. First row i get but now i want to get second row

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
SELECT * FROM  `users` ORDER BY  `id` DESC LIMIT 1 , 1
```