# How to get second MAXIMUM DATE in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, max

I want to fetch my record from mysql db. I want to fetch second maximum date from the record. But i failed

Here is my code

```
    <?php
include ("connection.php");
$q_opinion="SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, pr.opinion_id, pc.id, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, city.id, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
    LEFT join
(
  select max(notification_date) notification_date,
    client_id
  from og_ratings
  WHERE notification_date NOT IN (select max(notification_date) FROM og_ratings )
   ) r2
  on r.notification_date = r2.notification_date
  and r.client_id = r2.client_id
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)

";
$result = mysql_query($q_opinion) or die;
$rating = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $rating[] = $row['client_id'];
  $action[] = $row['atitle'];
  $opinion[] = $row['opinion'];
  $date[] = $row['notification_date'];
  $lrating[] = $row['ltitle'];
  $srating[] = $row['stitle'];
}
for ($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++) {
    if ($rating[$i] == "")continue;
     ?>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
          <td><?= $rating[$i] ?> </td>
           <td><?= $date[$i] ?> </td>
          <td><?= $opinion[$i] ?> </td>
         <td><?= $action[$i] ?> </td>
          <td><?= $lrating[$i] ?> </td>
           <td><?= $srating[$i] ?> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php   
}
?>
```

here is output of this code

[image]

In Output image you can see that it fetch all records from db. But i want to fetch only that data which have second maximum date.

How i can do it?

Comment: add "limit 1 offset 1 order by date desc" to your sql request

Comment: @Unex Where should i use limit in the end of query or in my subquery? please clear me but some sample code.

Comment: i CANT USE LIMIT COZ I USE SUBQUERY WHICH CONTAIN MULTIPLE RECORDS. IF I USE LIMIT THEN IT RETURENS ONLY ONE RECORD

Comment: @Strawberry *shhh, you'll wake up the OP and neighbours* - grin

Comment: @sunny quit the damn caps, will ya? (and under answer given) Or get that cat of yours off the keyboard. Throw it outside. Plus, you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516110/how-to-get-second-latest-row-from-mysql don't repost.

Comment: @Strawberry M not shouting. M dis heart by this behaviour. people did not seen the whole scenario and go for down vote . I just want to help bu all those people

Comment: FYI => http://email.about.com/od/netiquettetips/qt/Writing-In-All-Caps-Is-Like-Shouting.htm

Comment: @Fred-ii- If you can see the the difference in both question then you can understand both have different concept.

Comment: Are you asking the query for the second maximum date(i.e recent date compared to other date according to the calendar) or the second most maximum date that is appearing in the data.

Comment: @Mathew am asking about second most maximum date that is appearing in the data

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am really sory about that. I am not aware from this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wasn't fun to read your query, but I think the problem is here:

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT max(notification_date) notification_date, client_id
  FROM og_ratings
  WHERE notification_date NOT IN (
    SELECT max(notification_date)
    FROM og_ratings
)
```

if you want the maximum date for every client you need to GROUP BY client_id:

```
SELECT client_id, max(notification_date) notification_date
FROM og_ratings
GROUP BY client_id
```

if you want the second maximum there are few options, I'm using this one which is easier to understand but it's not necessarily the most performant:

```
SELECT client_id, max(notification_date) notification_date
FROM og_ratings
WHERE
  (client_id, notification_date) NOT IN (
    SELECT client_id, max(notification_date)
    FROM og_ratings GROUP BY client_id
  )
GROUP BY client_id
```

third problem, you're using a LEFT JOIN which means that you will return all values from og_ratings regardless if they are the second maximum or not. Use INNER JOIN on this context:

```
SELECT
  r.client_id,
  c.id,
  t.id,
  ..etc...
FROM
  og_ratings r INNER JOIN (
    SELECT client_id, max(notification_date) notification_2nd_date
    FROM og_ratings
    WHERE
      (client_id, notification_date) NOT IN (
        SELECT client_id, max(notification_date)
        FROM og_ratings GROUP BY client_id
      )
    GROUP BY client_id
   ) r2
  ON r.notification_date = r2.notification_2nd_date
     AND r.client_id = r2.client_id
  LEFT JOIN og_companies c ON r.client_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN og_actions a ON r.pacra_action = a.id
  LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
  LEFT JOIN og_lterms l ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
  LEFT JOIN og_sterms s ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
  LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc ON pc.id = pr.client_id
  LEFT JOIN city ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE
  r.client_id IN (
    SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations
    WHERE client_id = 50
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Alot.. I am very Thank full ti you. uuuummmmaaahhhhh

Comment: @fthiella goodness, you must have had a good reason or lots of free time to spare. Also, don't use mysql_*. Don't.

Comment: @sitilge I just formatted the query nicely and I quickly saw what was the problem :) yes, I answered about MySQL but I didn't say anything about php code, mysql_* functions are deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Note that the schema setup, `QueryA` and `QueryB` are all just for visualization.

Whereas, `QueryC` is the one for you to try with your data.

The reason this does not do a simple `order` by and `limit` that @Musa does is simple: you can have many rows with the second greatest date, not one. That is why is uses a variables for @grp and @prevdate to target the second group.

### Schema setup

```
-- drop table specimenA;
create table specimenA
(   mypk int auto_increment primary key,
    id int not null,    -- note, not autoinc or pk
    theDate date not null,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    otherThing varchar(20) not null
    -- etc
    -- not other indexes whatsoever
);
-- truncate table specimenA
insert specimenA (id,theDate,title,otherThing) values
(170,'2007-09-19','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2008-09-12','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2010-01-15','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2011-02-03','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2012-06-26','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2013-03-05','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2014-06-25','whatever','whatever'),
(170,'2015-06-09','whatever','whatever'),

(917,'2009-10-14','whatever','whatever'),
(917,'2008-12-31','whatever','whatever'),

(109,'2010-04-26','whatever','whatever'),
(109,'2011-03-02','whatever','whatever'),
(109,'2012-06-25','whatever','whatever'),
(109,'2013-01-04','whatever','whatever'),
(109,'2014-03-28','whatever','whatever'),
(109,'2015-03-18','whatever','whatever'),

(1057,'2014-03-28','whatever','whatever'),
(1057,'2014-11-21','whatever','whatever'),
(1057,'2015-08-13','whatever','whatever');
```

### QueryA

```
set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:=''; 
select id,theDate,title,otherThing,
@rn:=@rn+1 as rownum, 
@grp:=if(@prevdate=theDate,@grp,@grp+1) as descGrp, 
@prevdate:=theDate as unused 
from specimenA 
order by theDate DESC -- **** Note this
-- DESC means greatest first, as is most-recent first for dates
+------+------------+----------+------------+--------+---------+------------+
| id   | theDate    | title    | otherThing | rownum | descGrp | unused     |
+------+------------+----------+------------+--------+---------+------------+
| 1057 | 2015-08-13 | whatever | whatever   |      1 |       1 | 2015-08-13 |
|  170 | 2015-06-09 | whatever | whatever   |      2 |       2 | 2015-06-09 |
|  109 | 2015-03-18 | whatever | whatever   |      3 |       3 | 2015-03-18 |
| 1057 | 2014-11-21 | whatever | whatever   |      4 |       4 | 2014-11-21 |
|  170 | 2014-06-25 | whatever | whatever   |      5 |       5 | 2014-06-25 |
| 1057 | 2014-03-28 | whatever | whatever   |      6 |       6 | 2014-03-28 |
|  109 | 2014-03-28 | whatever | whatever   |      7 |       6 | 2014-03-28 |
|  170 | 2013-03-05 | whatever | whatever   |      8 |       7 | 2013-03-05 |
|  109 | 2013-01-04 | whatever | whatever   |      9 |       8 | 2013-01-04 |
|  170 | 2012-06-26 | whatever | whatever   |     10 |       9 | 2012-06-26 |
|  109 | 2012-06-25 | whatever | whatever   |     11 |      10 | 2012-06-25 |
|  109 | 2011-03-02 | whatever | whatever   |     12 |      11 | 2011-03-02 |
|  170 | 2011-02-03 | whatever | whatever   |     13 |      12 | 2011-02-03 |
|  109 | 2010-04-26 | whatever | whatever   |     14 |      13 | 2010-04-26 |
|  170 | 2010-01-15 | whatever | whatever   |     15 |      14 | 2010-01-15 |
|  917 | 2009-10-14 | whatever | whatever   |     16 |      15 | 2009-10-14 |
|  917 | 2008-12-31 | whatever | whatever   |     17 |      16 | 2008-12-31 |
|  170 | 2008-09-12 | whatever | whatever   |     18 |      17 | 2008-09-12 |
|  170 | 2007-09-19 | whatever | whatever   |     19 |      18 | 2007-09-19 |
+------+------------+----------+------------+--------+---------+------------+
```

And, taking the above select statement, and making it a derived table as alias `inR`, nested:

### QueryB

```
set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:=''; 
select id,theDate,title,otherthing 
from 
(   select id,theDate,title,otherThing,
    @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum, 
    @grp:=if(@prevdate=theDate,@grp,@grp+1) as descGrp, 
    @prevdate:=theDate as unused 
    from specimenA 
    order by theDate DESC  -- **** Note this
) inR 
where descGrp=2;
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| id  | theDate    | title    | otherthing |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| 170 | 2015-06-09 | whatever | whatever   |
+-----+------------+----------+------------+
```

And there is your second greatest date. Meaning second most-recent date.

---

So, taking your original select statement, same concept. The motivation for showing the above is simply this: `InR` is just a `Derived Table`, no more or less than your select statement that will become a Derived Table.

### QueryC

```
set @rn:=0,@grp:=0,@prevdate:=''; 

select client_id, cid, tid, aid, oid, opinion, notification_date,
ttitle, atitle, otitle, ltitle, stitle,
opinion_id, pcid, pr_client, address, liaison_one, 
cityid, head_office_id, city, cname
from
(   SELECT r.client_id as client_id,c.id as cid,t.id as tid,a.id as aid,o.id as oid,c.name as opinion, r.notification_date, 
    t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle, 
    pr.opinion_id, pc.id as pcid, pr.client_id as pr_client, pc.address, pc.liaison_one, 
    city.id as cityid, pc.head_office_id, city.city, pc.title as cname,
    @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum, 
    @grp:=if(@prevdate=r.notification_date,@grp,@grp+1) as descGrp, 
    @prevdate:=r.notification_date as unused 

    FROM og_ratings r 
        LEFT join
    (
      select max(notification_date) notification_date,
        client_id
      from og_ratings
      WHERE notification_date NOT IN (select max(notification_date) FROM og_ratings )
       ) r2
      on r.notification_date = r2.notification_date
      and r.client_id = r2.client_id
    LEFT JOIN og_companies c
    ON r.client_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
    ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
    LEFT JOIN og_actions a
    ON r.pacra_action = a.id
    LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
    ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
    LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
    ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
    LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
    ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
    LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
    ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
    ON pc.id = pr.client_id
    LEFT JOIN city
    ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
    WHERE r.client_id  IN (SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50)
    order by r.notification_date DESC
) inR
where descGrp=2
```

QueryC is what you go with. As it is two statements

- The initialization of the variables
- and the large query string

... you need to run them in that order with query, one for each, in that order, or use PHP [multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) and combine both in one call. That link in previous sentence was for mysqli, the concept is hereby revealed, modify accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply below query to get second max date in a table or with your requirement : -

```
select joiningDate from t_member order by joiningDate desc limit 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`. I have appended this code at end of the query:

```
SELECT 
    r.client_id,
    c.id,
    t.id,
    a.id,
    o.id,
    c.name as opinion, 
    r.notification_date, 
    t.title as ttitle,
    a.title as atitle,
    o.title as otitle, 
    l.title as ltitle, 
    s.title as stitle, 
    pr.opinion_id, 
    pc.id, 
    pr.client_id as pr_client, 
    pc.address, 
    pc.liaison_one, 
    city.id, 
    pc.head_office_id, 
    city.city, 
    pc.title as cname
FROM og_ratings r 
    LEFT join (
        select max(notification_date) notification_date,
            client_id
        from og_ratings
        WHERE notification_date NOT IN (select max(notification_date) FROM og_ratings )
   ) r2
  on r.notification_date = r2.notification_date
  and r.client_id = r2.client_id
LEFT JOIN og_companies c 
    ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
    ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
    ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
    ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
    ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
    ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_client_opinion_relations pr
    ON pr.opinion_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN pacra_clients pc
    ON pc.id = pr.client_id
LEFT JOIN city
    ON city.id = pc.head_office_id
WHERE 
    r.client_id  IN (
        SELECT opinion_id FROM pacra_client_opinion_relations WHERE client_id = 50
    )
ORDER BY r.notification_date DESC # Add this line
LIMIT 1 offset 1                  # and this line
```